# Combining multiple Text views horizontally with different modifiers - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to combine multiple Text views that have different modifiers. For example:

```
Text("This is") +
Text("important")
    .overlay(
        Text("overlayed text")
            .padding(.all, 10)
    ) +
Text("text")
```

The middle Text view returns **some View** since I applied the overlay modifier, but it cannot be combined with the other views since they are just Text views. I tried some methods, like I wrapped the Text view inside AnyView to erase its type, but + operator does not work with AnyView. I also tried to put them in HStack, but that messes it up if I have longer text strings. What other options can I use please, or are there any work-arounds?

Comment: With just `Text` itself, you can still use the `+` operator for modifiers which return as `Text` such as `.font`, `.foregroundColor`, `.fontWeight`, etc. I don't think you can achieve this with any SwiftUI stack unless you would try to create a custom stack.

Comment: I was able to use the `.foregroundColor`, `.fontWeight` modifiers just fine, but not others like `.overlay`, which is what I'd like to have. I was afraid that I can't achieve this with SwiftUI stack, are there any other work-arounds that I can use?

Comment: Tbh, I actually tried your problem with `LazyVStack` by printing one letter a time. It worked, but sadly you can't control the space between each letter, so it resulted in big gap between each letter. You can try making your own stack similar to `LazyVStack` but without big gap space I guess.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for trying that.